# I need help with this story!

Tags: character-development

My story "Finding Akita-Sama" and i`m stuck can someone help me get further into the story? What do I put next? How do I show and not tell? I really need help with this fanfic! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  This isn't precisely a duplicate, but this is the closest match I could find for part of your question, so maybe the answers will help you.  Beyond that, asking "how do I show not tell" without any details of your specific situation is too broad.  We also don't do critiques or tell you *what* to write, only *how*.  Please check out our short [tour].

Answer (score 0):

To show and not tell, use actions and dialogue between your characters. Make scenes. Basically, don't summarize the story/parts of the story as the narrator.

Comment: Read "Characters and Viewpoint" by Orson Scott Card